# Agregar calificaciones a varios alumnos laravel

Tags: laravel

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo la siguiente vista que me muestra todos los alumnos de una asignatura y sus notas correspondientes, como puedo hacer para editar dichos campos??

Este es mi controlador que recibe el id de la asignatura como tal y llama a los alumnos con sus calificaciones con la relacion.

```
public function agregarNota($id) 
{
    $asignatura = Asignatura::find($id);
    $alumnos = Asignatura::find($id)->alumnos;
    $calificaciones = Asignatura::find($id)->calificaciones;

    return view('calificaciones.agregar')->with('alumnos',$alumnos)->with('asignatura',$asignatura)->with('calificaciones',$calificaciones);
}
```

Necesito ayuda para editar esos campos, estoy acostumbrado al CRUD normal que es por filas.

Esta es la vista

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
  <tr>
   <th width="120">Rut</th>
   <th>N1</th>
   <th>N2</th>
   <th>N3</th>
   <th>N4</th>
   <th>N5</th>
   <th>N6</th>
   <th>N7</th>
   <th>N8</th>
   <th>Promedio</th>
   <th>Examen</th>
   <th>Final</th> 
  </tr>
   @foreach ($calificaciones as $c)
    <tr>
     <td>{{$c->alumno->rut}}</td>
           <td>{!! Form::text('n1', $c->n1, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}</td>
           <td>{!! Form::text('n2', $c->n2, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}</td>
           <td>{!! Form::text('n3', $c->n3, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}</td>
           <td>{!! Form::text('n4', $c->n4, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}</td>  
           <td>{!! Form::text('n5', $c->n5, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}</td>
           <td>{!! Form::text('n6', $c->n6, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}</td>
           <td>{!! Form::text('n7', $c->n7, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}</td>
           <td>{!! Form::text('n8', $c->n8, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}</td>  
           <td>{!! Form::text('promedio', $c->promedio, array('class' => 'form-control', 'readonly' => 'readonly')) !!}</td>
           <td>{!! Form::text('examen', $c->examen, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}</td>
           <td>{!! Form::text('final', $c->final, array('class' => 'form-control', 'readonly' => 'readonly')) !!}</td>          
      
    </tr>
   @endforeach

 </table>
```

Comment: ¿cuál es el problema que no te permite editar los campos? No entiendo eso que el CRUD funciona por filas, que yo sepa, CRUD no tiene nada que ver con la disposición visual de los campos.

Comment: El problema es que nose como colocar ese boton editar, a lo que me refiero es que estoy acostumbrado a colocar el tipico boton show, edit o delete en un td de "Opciones" pero eso siempre me altera solo una fila. Ahora quiero editar por ejemplo el N1 de todos los alumnos juntos, como podria hacerlo??

Comment: quizá una solución asincrona sea mas útil esta vez :P Agrega un evento onFocusLost a los campos de notas, cuando pierda el foco, envias el id del alumno, el de la nota y la nota al servidor. Asi no tienes que esperar a que se llenen todos para enviarlo... y puedes terminar de llenar las notas en cualquier momento :P

Comment: Tal vez no sea exactamente lo que buscas, pero ¿qué tal un solo botón para guardar todos los campos? y así evitar el manejo "por columnas".

Answer (score 0):

Lo que puedes hacer es una llamada asíncrona cada vez que quieras modificar una nota. Puedes hacerlo de varias maneras, en mi caso voy a utilizar [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios). En el ejemplo que pongo cambie los `text` del laravel collective a `input` ya que no se como se pasan funciones javascript dentro de este.

**VISTA**

```
@foreach ($calificaciones as $c)
<tr>
    <td>{{$c->alumno->rut}}</td>

   <td><input type="text" id="n1[{{$loop->iteration}}]" 
   onblur="actualizar('n1[{{$loop->iteration}}]','n1',{{$asignatura->id}})" 
   value="{{$c->n2}}">
   .
   .
   .
@endforeach
```

Lo que se hace aquí es asignarle una id a todas las notas y a cada iteracion con [$loop->iteration](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#the-loop-variable) (se veria algo asi `n1[0],n1[1],n1[2]`), esto se lo hace con el fin de saber cual nota se va a modificar al momento de hacer la llamada.

Una vez hecho esto se utiliza el evento [onblur](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onblur.asp) de javascript, así cada vez que un usuario modifique una nota y salga del input este se active. Ahora asignamos la función `actualizar` que va a tener como parámetros el id del input, el nombre de la columna que se va a modificar, y el id de la fila de esas notas (en este caso le puse asignatura ya que no se como tienes las tablas). A continuación el script:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
     <script>
            function actualizar(nota,nombre,id) {
             nota = document.getElementById(nota).value;

              axios.put('/asignatura/'+ id, {nombre: nota})
                .then(function (res) {
                 //si se quiere retornar algo
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                 //si sucede algún error
                });

          }
        </script>
```

Aqui es donde se realiza la llamada asincrona a tu ruta de laravel que actualiza los datos, como no se tus rutas la puse en `asignatura/{id}`.

**RUTA**

```
Route::put('asignatura/{id}',function(Request $request, $id){
        Asignatura::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all());
    });
```

Aqui creas la ruta que actualizará el modelo.

**MODELO**

```
protected $fillable = [
       'n1','n2','n3', //...
    ];
```

En el modelo de `asignatura` se debe agregar el `$fillable` de todas las columnas de notas para que nos permita cambiarlas al momento de editarlas.

**Nota**

Si tienes problemas con el csrf de laravel debes agregar lo siguiente:

```
<script>
    window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]) !!};
</script>
```

y antes de hacer la llamada en axios:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = Laravel.csrfToken;
```